# Getting a JSON object from a target host. Error: Target host must not be null

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to figure out how JSON works right now and so I thought what better way than making a little JSON Reading Project! I want the user to use an EditText and Search button for the user to use and find out if the website the user enters has any JSON and then display it in a textbox. Right now I am testing the site: **itunes.apple.com/search?term=**

As you can see in my code I am just setting those variables without the EditText and Search button until I can get this thing working. I am getting the following error:

```
11-03 20:30:58.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8608): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-03 20:30:58.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8608): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-03 20:30:58.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
11-03 20:30:58.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
11-03 20:30:58.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
11-03 20:30:58.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
11-03 20:30:58.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-03 20:30:58.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-03 20:30:58.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-03 20:30:58.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-03 20:30:58.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8608):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-03 20:30:58.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8608): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
 Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=itunes.apple.com/search
```

I believe that this is because of the following line: **HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);** but I do not know how I am suppose to correct the host from being null. I have the feeling that it has something to do with the question mark or something. Or maybe I'm just approaching this the wrong way. Please take into consideration that this is my first project with JSON. Maybe I need a simpler tutorial on using JSON so that I understand it thoroughly. Thanks!

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView fetchText;
EditText httpEntryBox,jsonEntryBox;
Button search_button_http, search_button_json;
HTTP_Fetcher http_fetch;

HttpClient client;
final static String URL = "itunes.apple.com/search?term=";
JSONObject json;
InputMethodManager imm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fetchText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fetchText);

    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    new Read().execute("artistName");


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public JSONObject search( String searchItem ) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException, URISyntaxException{
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
    url.append(searchItem);

    String finished_url = url.toString();

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(finished_url);
    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);

    int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    if (status == 200){
        HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data);
        return array.getJSONObject(0);
    }else{
        Log.e("Search","fetch error");
        return null;
    }


}

public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            json = search("lilwayne");
            return json.getString(params[0]);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        fetchText.setText(result);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing the *http* scheme, so instead of:

```
final static String URL = "itunes.apple.com/search?term=";
```

put:

```
final static String URL = "http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=";
```

**EDIT**
Even if that will work, parsing of JSON will fail because of this line: `JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data);` - this assumes the response is an array, but it's a JSONObject that contains two entries: `resultsCount` and `results`. You need to make it a `JSONObject`: `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data);`. The internet is full of `android json parsing` tutorials. Here's a [relevant article](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/).